# I can't sum the values of a column whose values are generated using if statement

Tags: function, excel-formula, excel-2007

Sum function is not helping me sum the column, i even tried to manually enter all the cells but that also does not help. Even if there is values in the column, I get 0 as the answer in the cell where I have entered the sum function.

Comment: are the fields declared as number type?

Comment: i changed the fields but it did not work

Comment: I just opened and excel put some numbers on a column put this formula `=SUM(A1:A6)` and it worked with no problems. You need to specify more details.

Comment: it works that way. but the cells i'm trying to sum have data derived by using if statement and has a circular reference

Comment: You said you tried to enter values by hand and didn't worked. What is the formula that you are using?

Comment: You might also want to look over [this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/09/16/excel-circular-references/) if you have circular reference.

Comment: i'm using if to match dates in two diff workbooks, so if i enter a date in one workbook and then the value is recorded in the cell adjacent to the corresponding date

Answer (score 0):

I have the following condition for 10 cells in a column `=IF(B1=0,20,2)` and then the sum for the cells `=SUM(A1:A10)`. The column is autoupdated when `B1` is updated and also the sum is updated when the values of the cells change.

If you have different workbooks the if changes to this `=IF([d.xlsx]Tabelle1!$A$1=0,2,10)`. Where `d.xslx` is the name of the second workbook where you check the value `Tabelle1` is the name of the sheet and `$A$1` is the checked cell.

Comment: the false value that i use is a circular reference, so i think this might be the issue. But this reference is important as i need the record of previous inputs

Comment: get rid of the circular reference and check if it works like that.

Comment: this was done to reduce the efforts in inputting the values daily by making the condition of if statement as dates. If i change the dates in my input sheet it automatically gets recorded in my daily sheet with respect to the date. But if i don't give circular reference then the previous values are removed.

Comment: Mine is like suppose C4 is the cell so      'C4=IF([d.xlsx]Tabelle1!$A$1=[E.xlsx]sheet1!,[d.xlsx]Tabelle1!$B$1,C4)'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IF formula does not have "" around your values. For example, make sure it looks like this: =IF(A1="Y",1,0)